# Running JavaScript function immediately with context as parameter

Tags: javascript, scope

In lot's of JavaScript libraries I see the following code:

```
(function(context){


})(this);
```

Why do these libraries use this? And what does this code do?

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ and `this` references the global object.

Comment: On the "root" `this` is the global object... `window` in the browser, not so in node, so it decouples the library from the platform it's running on.

Comment: I'd argue that this isn't a dupe of the marked question. Specifically, it doesn't address passing in `this`. I'd be surprised if this wasn't answered elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate ether. In the marked duplicate question it's not about the context.

Comment: You need to indicate what "this" is a little more clearly to consider reopening.  Nobody can tell the difference because the post body is so vague.

Comment: What I posted was actually the whole Javascript file. So this would contain this.document, this.window etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an IEFE function which receives `this` as a parameter.

What it does is avoid scoping/closure issues by referring to `context` instead of `this` which varies when used in different places.

By referring to `context` you can be sure that it will remain `this` passed as argument and nothing else. But if you use `this` directly in the code, then closure and scoping issues will arise.